# Redirect one sub-domain to another without url change

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what I'm trying to do with htaccess and can't find my way:

```
mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com
web.mydomain.com -> web.mydomain.com
anything-else.mydomain.com -> web.mydomain.com **without changing the browser url**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Force www prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Force https prefix on www subdomain
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Move non-www to subdomain 'web'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^web/ /web%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
RewriteEngine On
```